# recursively move, rename and zip files

Tags: zip, rename, cp

I have a folder structure like this

`Folder1 Folder2 Folder3 ...FolderXYZ`

Each of these Folders contains around 500 files named like

`event-yyyy-mm-dd-0001.jpg_backup event-yyyy-mm-dd-0002.jpg_backup ...` and

`event-yyyy-mm-dd-0001.jpg event-yyyy-mm-dd-0002.jpg ....`

I need to copy all `*.jpg_backup` files from `Folder1 Folder2 ...` to a new created subdirectory within a diffrent folder `Folderexisting`, strip the `_backup` from the filenames, and make a zip with all the renamed files, named after parent directory (e.g. `Folder1.zip`). 
The script should be able to do this recursively for all folders. OS is a Debian Wheezy with no GUI.

THX in advance